# Copy List Views to Another independent existing list SharePoint2013

Tags: list, view

I have a dozen Lists, each independent.  Each houses the same columns, titles, etc.  But, the data within each list is unique to that list; one list for apples.  Another list for oranges, etc.  I need to make a VIEW for EACH list that is identical in terms of the columns displayed in some given order.  For example, the Apple list will always show Quantity, price, location, vendor, etc.  Same columns as the Orange list will show on its page.  Can I make a view in Apples that dictates what columns display in what order and just copy that view into my other lists?  This is not a templating issue... the lists already exist with independent data.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at: http://get-spscripts.com/2012/02/managing-creating-and-deleting.html, describing how to create the same view across site collections. It seems the concept is the same.

Thanks - Matiur Rahman